# Creating a relationship between 2 dataframes in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to create a mapping as follows:

`df_input_1`: this is a grouped data

```
+------+------+
|Hier_1|Hier_2|
+------+------+
|   Jim|   Pan|
|   Tak|   Can|
|   Pac|   Dan|
|   Foe|   Man|
|   Yat|   Van|
+------+------+
```

`df_output_1`: Created after applying logic

```
+---+---------+--------------------+---+
| Sr|Parent_Sr|                Name| ID|
+---+---------+--------------------+---+
|123|       NA|Jim is father of Pan|Jim|
|456|       NA|Tak is father of Can|Tak|
|789|       NA|Pac is father of Dan|Pac|
|143|       NA|Foe is father of Man|Foe|
|457|       NA|Yat is father of Van|Yat|
+---+---------+--------------------+---+
```

`df_output_2`: Second dataframe after using another input.

```
+---+---------+--------------------+---+
| Sr|Parent_Sr|                Name| ID|
+---+---------+--------------------+---+
|998|       NA|Pan is father of Fen|Pan|
|887|       NA|Can is father of Den|Can|
|776|       NA|Dan is father of Qen|Dan|
|665|       NA|Man is father of Men|Man|
|554|       NA|Van is father of Ren|Van|
+---+---------+--------------------+---+
```

Expected `df_output_2`:

| Sr | Parent_Sr | Name | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 998 | 123 | Pan is father of Fen | Pan |
| 887 | 456 | Can is father of Den | Can |
| 776 | 789 | Dan is father of Qen | Dan |
| 665 | 143 | Man is father of Men | Man |
| 554 | 457 | Van is father of Ren | Van |

The values in `Sr` column will always be unique and NOT in sequence. I have been able work on this in python as follows:

This works:

```
df_output_1_2 = df_output_1.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'])
mapping = pd.Series(df_output_1_2['Sr'].values, index=df_output_1_2['ID'])
df_output_2['Parent_Sr'] = df_output_2['Parent_Sr'].fillna(df_output_2['ID'].map(mapping))
```

The important problem is also filling up only the blank entries in `Parent_Sr`.

Not sure how to get this done in pyspark.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. But as per the shown inputs and the desired output, I believe what you want is simply join `df_output_2` and `df_input_1` on `ID = Hier_2` to get the relation between `ID`s then join with `df_output_1` on `ID = Hier_1` to get `Sr` values :

```
df_output_2 = df_output_2.alias("out2").join(
    df_input_1.alias("in1"),
    col("out2.ID") == col("in1.Hier_2"), "left"
) \
    .join(
    df_output_1.alias("out1"),
    col("out1.ID") == col("in1.Hier_1"), "left"
) \
    .selectExpr("out2.Sr", "coalesce(out2.Parent_Sr, out1.Sr) as Parent_Sr", "out2.name", "out2.ID")

df_output_2.show()

#+---+---------+--------------------+---+
#| Sr|Parent_Sr|                name| ID|
#+---+---------+--------------------+---+
#|998|      123|Pan is father of Fen|Pan|
#|665|      143|Man is father of Men|Man|
#|887|      456|Can is father of Den|Can|
#|554|      457|Van is father of Ren|Van|
#|776|      789|Dan is father of Qen|Dan|
#+---+---------+--------------------+---+
```